# QTP - Checking dynamic pages

Tags: testing, qtp

I'm trying to check if a value is contained in the innertext of a webelement but I'm having a little problem: frames seem to change at every refresh of the pages. 
These are the steps I've recorded:

```
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_header").Image("Gestione Anagrafiche").Click<br>
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl").WebEdit("pdrBean.pdrPod").Set parameter("POD")<br>
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl").WebButton("Cerca").Click
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl_2").Image("show_files").Click
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl_6").Image("Lente").Click

    cctype = Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl_7").WebElement("arrow_down").GetROProperty("innertext")<br>
    DataAct = Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_appl_7").WebElement("arrow_down_2").GetROProperty("innertext")<br>

    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("dme2_header").Image("Gestione Anagrafiche").Click
```

The frames "dme2_appl6" and "dme2_appl7" changes at every refresh of the two pages. 
The question is simple: how can I rewrite these two actions to make them universal?
I've tried to do something like:

```
    Set objFrame = Frame("title:=dme2_appl_.")
```

and then

```
    Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").objFrame.Image("Lente").Click
```

But QTP gives me an error in return: "property or method not supported by the object"

Answer (score 2):

Please try using the below code

```
Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Image("Lente").Click
```

**Avoid using the "Frame" and if you really want to use it, put regex for name property of Frame.**

Go to Object Properties--> Click on the Frame object --> Mandatory Properties--> Change name property as
like iFrame_213123123 to i.*

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a frame object that way. When you write `Page().Frame()` UFT sets the frame's parent in different way than if you first create the Frame. 
Think of `Frame()` as a function that behaves differently when called on a Page or as a free function.

Try:

```
 Browser("SystemPage").Page("SystemP").Frame("title:=dme2_appl_.")
```

Comment: Tried that too but QTP says that the frame is not in the object repository... :S

Comment: @LeonGuerrero, are you sure that you used the descriptive programming syntax (`:=`)  ?

Comment: The blank betwen the "." and the "Frame" should be removed

Comment: @TheBlastOne, It works either way but I agree it's more aesthetic this way.

Comment: Didn't know it works with the blank, too, so nevermind.